# Responsive Background image for Nav

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to contain logos inside a nav back image.. Here's the link: http://icreatif.com/testing/wht_hs_cat_test-site/

Comment: change `witdh:xxxPX` to `max-width:100%; width:auto`

Comment: So whats your point here this link doesnt say anything to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: The image is in the background or are you referring to the logo's?